# How to set a default value for parameter POJO in SpringBoot service

Tags: spring-boot

I created a spring boot service, which uses POJO class as url parameters wrapper.

Here is the POJO class:

```java
@Data
@Builder
public class FindStoresRequest {
    private Integer pageNum;
    private Integer pageSize;
}
```

And here is service endpoint:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/stores", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Store> getStores(FindStoresRequest findStoresRequest) {
        return storeService.findStores(findStoresRequest.getPageNum(), findStoresRequest.getPageSize());
}
```

How can I set default value for `pageNum` to be `1` and `pageSize` to be `10` in the POJO class `FindStoresRequest`?

Does it make sense to use `javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue` annotation? I'm not quite sure it is ok to mix `JAX-RS` with spring boot.

#### Edit 2022-03-17

I managed to get it work after adding `Jersey 2`, something I intended to do anyway.

Now my stack is `Spring Boot` + `Jersey 2`. I'm using `@DefaultValue` annotation to make it work.

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FindStoresRequest {

  @QueryParam("storeCategories")
  private List<String> storeCategories;

  @QueryParam("latitude")
  private Double latitude;

  @QueryParam("longitude")
  private Double longitude;

  @QueryParam("distance")
  private Double distance;

  @QueryParam("pageNum")
  @DefaultValue("1")
  private Integer pageNum;

  @QueryParam("pageSize")
  @DefaultValue("10")
  private Integer pageSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong using

```
public class FindStoresRequest {
    private Integer pageNum = 1;
    private Integer pageSize = 10;
}
```

This should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Not sure why. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a Custom Validation of your pojo
and determine if the fields are null assign a default value by example:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Constraint(validatedBy = FindStoresRequestValidation.FindStoresRequestValidationHelper.class)
public @interface FindStoresRequestValidation {
    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    class FindStoresRequestValidationHelper implements ConstraintValidator<FindStoresRequestValidation, FindStoresRequest> {

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(FindStoresRequest findStoresRequest, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            if(null == findStoresRequest.getPageNum())
                findStoresRequest.setPageNum(1);
            if(null == findStoresRequest.getPageSize())
                findStoresRequest.getPageSize(10);
            
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@Builder
@FindStoresRequestValidation
public class FindStoresRequest {
    private Integer pageNum;
    private Integer pageSize;
}
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/stores", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Store> getStores(@Valid FindStoresRequest findStoresRequest, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        return storeService.findStores(findStoresRequest.getPageNum(), findStoresRequest.getPageSize());
}
```